# Dynamicly Write and Print at RunTime FlowDocument in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

hello Friends Today I  am  trying to make small wpf app present for my wife. I want she can wrıte at runtime and print what she write in flowdocument. ı can do everthings at design time but ı want write ar run time  here my solution probably ı must use ı ınotifyProperty changed  or binding text of flowdocument to printDlg  What should I do        can you hellp me please

```
/// <summary>
/// This method creates a dynamic FlowDocument. You can add anything to this
/// FlowDocument that you would like to send to the printer
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private FlowDocument CreateFlowDocument()
{
// Create a FlowDocument
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
// Create a Section
Section sec = new Section();
// Create first Paragraph
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
// Create and add a new Bold, Italic and Underline
Bold bld = new Bold();
bld.Inlines.Add(new Run("First Paragraph"));
Italic italicBld = new Italic();
italicBld.Inlines.Add(bld);
Underline underlineItalicBld = new Underline();
underlineItalicBld.Inlines.Add(italicBld);
// Add Bold, Italic, Underline to Paragraph
p1.Inlines.Add(underlineItalicBld);
// Add Paragraph to Section
sec.Blocks.Add(p1);
// Add Section to FlowDocument
doc.Blocks.Add(sec);
return doc;
}









private void print(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// Create a PrintDialog
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
// Create a FlowDocument dynamically. 
FlowDocument doc = CreateFlowDocument();
doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
// Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
// Call PrintDocument method to send document to printer
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Hello WPF Printing."); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WYSIWYG editing, WPF provides a ready-made control. The WPF RichTextBox control can edit XAML Flow Documents natively.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am totaly forgot  lıke you said FlowDocument in RichTextBox is Editable here  ı Fınd the best solution  you can print and save pdf,xps.format

/******************************************************************************************/

```
// Handle "Save RichTextBox Content" button click.
private void SaveRTBContent(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {

        // Clone the source document's content into a new FlowDocument. 
        // This is because the pagination for the printer needs to be 
        // done differently than the pagination for the displayed page. 
        // We print the copy, rather that the original FlowDocument. 
        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(); 
        TextRange source = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd); 
        source.Save(s, DataFormats.Xaml); 
        FlowDocument copy = new FlowDocument(); 
        TextRange dest = new TextRange(copy.ContentStart, copy.ContentEnd); 
        dest.Load(s, DataFormats.Xaml); 

        // Create a XpsDocumentWriter object, implicitly opening a Windows common print dialog, 
        // and allowing the user to select a printer. 

        // get information about the dimensions of the seleted printer+media. 
        PrintDocumentImageableArea ia = null; 
        System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter docWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref ia); 

        if (docWriter != null && ia != null) 
        { 
            DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)copy).DocumentPaginator; 

            // Change the PageSize and PagePadding for the document to match the CanvasSize for the printer device. 
            paginator.PageSize = new Size(ia.MediaSizeWidth, ia.MediaSizeHeight); 
            Thickness t = new Thickness(72);  // copy.PagePadding; 
            copy.PagePadding = new Thickness( 
                             Math.Max(ia.OriginWidth, t.Left), 
                               Math.Max(ia.OriginHeight, t.Top), 
                               Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeWidth - (ia.OriginWidth + ia.ExtentWidth), t.Right), 
                               Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeHeight - (ia.OriginHeight + ia.ExtentHeight), t.Bottom)); 

            copy.ColumnWidth = double.PositiveInfinity; 
            //copy.PageWidth = 528; // allow the page to be the natural with of the output device 

            // Send content to the printer. 
            docWriter.Write(paginator); 
        } 

    }
```